# Using pandas to combine csv by comparing a key ("id")

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSVs with basically the same content, but spelling mistakes are removed from one, `fileA.csv`, and `fileB.csv` gets updated (as in new rows are added) from upstream (a limesurvey installation). How do I "combine" these two files using Pandas by checking the "id" column?

I have tried to iterate over both files using Python `csv` module, but it didn't ended successfully. I managed to combine the two CSVs using the code below, but it just added the same columns ending with "_x" and "_y" ...

```
import pandas as pd

fileA = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv_corrected",sep=";")
fileB = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv",sep=";")

merged = pd.merge(fileB, fileA, on='id')

print(merged.to_csv())
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by combining ? What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming spelling mistakes being removed from `fileA.csv` means you want to keep row in `fileA.csv`, but add any rows in `fileB.csv` that do not exist in `fileA.csv`.

As a general rule you should read in your DataFrames so the *index* is set to your primary key. Having done that, I think the simple way to do what you want is `combine_first()`:

---

**Example:**

```
> cat FileA.csv 
id,0,  1,  2,  3,  4
A,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000
B,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000
C,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000
D,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000
> cat FileB.csv 
id,0,  1,  2,  3,  4
A,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000
B,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000
E,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000
F,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000
> dfA = pd.read_csv('FileA.csv', header=0, index_col='id') 
> dfB = pd.read_csv('FileB.csv', header=0, index_col='id')
> dfA.combine_first(dfB)
```

**Gives:**

```
           0         1         2         3         4
id                                                  
A  +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000
B  +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000
C  +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000
D  +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000 +1.000000
E  +0.000000 +0.000000 +0.000000 +0.000000 +0.000000
F  +0.000000 +0.000000 +0.000000 +0.000000 +0.000000
```

There is also `DataFrame.update()` but annoyingly, its behavior is inconsistent with `dict.update()`, as won't add new "keys" (index items).